# MediaPlayer getDuration returns -1412558917

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm totally lost in this. I found the code pretty simple, and didn't find in the documentation any reason why would return a negative number that large. The code is as follows

```
private int getDuration(String audioPath) throws Exception {
   mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(); // This variable was created globally
   mediaPlayer.setDataSource(audioPath);
   return mediaPlayer.getDuration(); // Here it returns -1412558917 in every audio file i record, no matter if it's 3 seconds long or 8

}
```

I think that it doesn't matter how I record it, but if I'm mistaken I'll add the code. The format I save the file is 3gp. I'm able to reproduce the audio after this, so I don't know what might be the problem

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried adding `mediaPlayer.prepare();` before you return the duration?

Comment: I feel dumb now. I was able to solve it that way. Do you have any link where I can read to understand better why this is neccesary? Thank you!

Comment: Anytime :) remember to mark the answer as the accepted if it worked for you.

You can read more about Mediaplayer here - https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html